# Prove that there exist a set $ S⊆V $ for a graph G which contains a matching M, such that there are $ frac{|E|+m}{2} $ between S and V\S

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

Let $ G =(V,E)$ be a graph.
Suppose that G contains a Matching M consisting of m edges. I have to prove that there exists a set $ S⊆V $ such that there are at least: $  \frac{|E|+m}{2} $ edges between S and V\S.

I know that it can be proven by determining the expectation of a suitable random variable, but if I choose S randomly among all subsets of V it is only suffice to obtain $\frac{|E|}{2}  $ edges.

Any tips how to determine such a suitable random variable?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

For every edge $vw$ of the matching, flip a coin to put either $v$ or $w$ in $S$.

For all vertices not in the matching, proceed as usual and flip a coin to decide if they're in $S$ or not.

Comment: I just found an answer in this link: <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54789/if-g-has-a-matching-with-k-edges-then-it-has-a-bipartite-subgraph-with-e?rq=1> which seems to me it  explains the same think that you have written..

Comment: Yes, that's the same idea.